# Significance of ORDER BY <particular multiple number>

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Help me understand the following snippet:

```
...
ORDER BY 2, 12, 11
```

Comment: That means order by 2nd column, 12th column, 11th column in your selected columns

Comment: Does this mean first it will order by 2nd column then, 12th column and then 11th column?

Comment: Please tag only the database of interest.

Comment: Yes, if you have `SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM table_name ORDER BY 2, 4` then it's is same as `ORDER BY  col2, col4`.

Comment: Why not play around at [W3Schools' SQL ORDER BY Keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp). It explains many scenarios and let's you experiment

Comment: Please note that this isn't something I'd recommend copying. The premise behind relational/SQL was that columns should be referenced by *name*, not by *position*. This syntax works precisely in opposition to that principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL `ORDER BY` is the Keyword used to Order your Resultset based on the values of a Particular column or Columns either Ascending or Descending order.

The `ORDER BY` is Given as the Last Statement in a `SELECT`.

The Syntax is :

```
SELECT
    <List of Columns>
    FROM <Table Name>
    <Filter Conditions > -- Optional
    <Group By and Having> - Optional
    ORDER BY 
    <Column 1> <ASC or DESC>,
    <Column 2> <ASC or DESC>,
    .......
    <Column N> <ASC or DESC>,
```

You Can Either Give the Column Names or the Ordinal Position of the Column in the Select List.

For Example :

```
SELECT
    EmpId,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    Age,
    ContactNumber
    FROM Employee
        ORDER BY 
            FirstName,
            Age
```

Can Also be written as

```
SELECT
    EmpId,
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    Age,
    ContactNumber
    FROM Employee
        ORDER BY 
            2,4
```

in the second one, I'm giving the Ordinal position of Columns FirstName and Age instead of specifying the Column Name.

This approach is more useful when you have 2 columns with the Same Name in your Resultset.

Example :

```
SELECT
    EmpId,
    *
    ContactNumber
    FROM Employee
        ORDER BY 
            EmpId
```

The above will give you the following error

> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 Ambiguous column name 'EmpId'.

So Instead you can say

```
  SELECT
    EmpId,
    *
    ContactNumber
    FROM Employee
        ORDER BY 
            1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get and learn in details from the below query. Multiple column `OrderBy` is useful when similar values are present in table.

```
Create Table Orders (Id int, ProdName Varchar(20))
insert into Orders Values (1, 'A'), (4, 'C'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'E'), (4, 'G'), (5, 'D'), (6, 'F'), (7, 'G')

Select * from Orders
order by 1 -- Order By Id Ascending

Select * from Orders
order by 1 desc -- Order By Id Descending

Select * from Orders
order by 2 -- Order By Name Ascending

Select * from Orders
order by 2 desc -- Order By Name Descending

Select * from Orders
order by 1, 2 -- Order By Id first and then Name Ascending. 
-- It will come same Id first and same name later

Select * from Orders
order by 1 asc, 2 desc --First priority of Id ascending then Name in descending order

Select * from Orders
order by 1, 2 desc
```

You can find the live demo [**Live Demo Here**](https://rextester.com/LAV39798)